# Length metric and edge-path metric on a finite dimesional $CAT(0)$ cube complex are coarsely equivalent

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to find a proof for the statement in the title:

> Length metric and edge-path metric on the vertex set of a finite dimensional $CAT(0)$ cube complex are coarsely equivalent.

Length metric, let's say $ d_1 $, is simply the shortest way in the complex, while the edge-path metric, let's say $ d_2 $, is the shortest way, using only edges. It's obvious from the definition that if $ d_1(x,y) < R $, then $ d_2(x,y) < R $. The converse is what gets me - how do I find, for every $ R $, a constant $ S $ such that if $ d_2(x,y) <R $, then $ d_1(x,y) < S $?

I would appreciate some help on that.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the $\mathrm{CAT}(0)$ condition -- it works for any finite-dimensional cubical complex $X$, assuming each cube is isometrically embedded.

Let $X$ be a $\mathrm{CAT}(0)$ cubical complex, and let $d_n$ denote the geodesic metric on the $n$-skeleton $X^n$.  It is easy to check that
$$
d_{n-1}(x,y) \,\leq\, \sqrt{2}\, d_n(x,y)
$$
for all $x,y\in X^{n-1}$, since this formula holds for points on the boundary of a single $n$-cube, and a geodesic in $X^n$ can pass through only finitely many $n$-cubes. It follows that
$$
d_1(x,y) \,\leq\, \bigl(\sqrt{2}\bigr)^{n-1}\, d_n(x,y)
$$
for all $n$ and all $x,y\in X^1$. In the case where $X$ is $n$-dimensional, the metric $d_n$ on the right is the same as the given metric on $X$.